# Not able to remove host name from Alert window

Tags: javascript, alert

I am displaying alert for one condition but not able to remove server name from the alert.
I am using below code:-

JS :-

```
    $(".btn-na").click(function() {
    let n = $('.answers.disabled').not($(this).closest('.answers')).length
    if (n >= 3) {
      alert('You can only disable 3');
      return
    }
    $(this).closest('.answers').find("input").attr('disabled', !$(this).closest('.answers').find("input").is(":disabled"));
    $(this).closest('.answers').toggleClass('disabled')
  })
```

Comment: There is always server name in the alert 'title'.

Comment: You have to use a custom alert box